# Show that the open disk $D(a,r)$ is connected.

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Let $a\in\mathbb{C}$ and $r>0$. Show that the open disk $D(a,r)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}\colon \vert z-a\vert<r\}$ is connected.

---

The disk is connected if there exists a path between any two points $b,c\in D(a,r)$. First we parametrise the path between these points by letting $p(t)=b+t(c-b)$, $0\le t\le 1$. Then we must show $\vert p(t)-a\vert < r$. We have

\begin{align}
\vert p(t) - a\vert &= \vert b+t(c-b)-a\vert \\
&= \vert b-a+tc-tb + ta-ta\vert \\
&= \vert (b-a) + t(c-a)-t(b-a)\vert \\
&\le \vert b-a\vert + t\vert c-a\vert + t\vert b-a\vert \\
&\le r(1+2t)
\end{align}

Clearly I have gone wrong but can't find out where.

Comment: Sign error in the first line, $p(t) - a = b +t(c-b) - a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer thanks I have fixed this. However, it doesn't seem to make a difference.

Comment: You're too generous with the triangle inequality. Write things as $(1-t)(b-a) + t(c-a)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{align*} |p(t)-a|&=|b+t(c-b)-a|=|b-a+tc-tb|\\&=|(1-t)b-a+tc|\\&=|(1-t)b-a+at-at+tc|\\&=|(1-t)(b-a)+t(c-a)|\\&\leq (1-t)|b-a|+t|c-a|\\&<(1-t)\epsilon+t\epsilon=\epsilon\end{align*}

Comment: I love it when people give detailed steps. Perfect proof!